# L2TP / IPSec failing to connect (Kubuntu 17.10)

Tags: kubuntu, vpn, 17.10, ipsec

I'm trying to connect to the corporate VPN from Kubuntu 17.10. I have network-manager-l2tp installed (version 1.2.8). The output I'm getting:

```
Nov 28 17:20:48 T460 NetworkManager[667]: initiating Main Mode IKE_SA 41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332[1] to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Nov 28 17:20:48 T460 NetworkManager[667]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]
Nov 28 17:20:48 T460 NetworkManager[667]: sending packet: from 192.168.43.232[500] to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (240 bytes)
Nov 28 17:20:48 T460 NetworkManager[667]: sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Nov 28 17:20:48 T460 NetworkManager[667]: sending packet: from 192.168.43.232[500] to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (240 bytes)
Nov 28 17:20:48 T460 NetworkManager[667]: destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification
Nov 28 17:20:48 T460 NetworkManager[667]: establishing connection '41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332' failed
Nov 28 17:20:48 T460 nm-l2tp-service[3673]: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
Nov 28 17:20:48 T460 NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1511889648.3131] vpn-connection[0x55fe5d8fe2f0,41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332,"WorkVPN",0]: VPN service disappeared
Nov 28 17:20:48 T460 NetworkManager[667]: <warn>  [1511889648.3161] vpn-connection[0x55fe5d8fe2f0,41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332,"WorkVPN",0]: VPN connection: failed to connect: 'Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying'
Nov 28 17:23:58 T460 NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1511889838.9310] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332" name="WorkVPN" pid=1017 uid=1000 result="success"
Nov 28 17:23:58 T460 NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1511889838.9371] vpn-connection[0x55fe5d8fe4e0,41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332,"WorkVPN",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 3759
Nov 28 17:23:58 T460 NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1511889838.9477] vpn-connection[0x55fe5d8fe4e0,41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332,"WorkVPN",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Nov 28 17:24:01 T460 nm-l2tp-service[3759]: Check port 1701
Nov 28 17:24:01 T460 NetworkManager[667]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec failed: starter is not running
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 NetworkManager[667]: Starting strongSwan 5.5.1 IPsec [starter]...
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 NetworkManager[667]: Loading config setup
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 NetworkManager[667]: Loading conn '41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332'
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 NetworkManager[667]: found netkey IPsec stack
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 charon: 00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.5.1, Linux 4.14.2-041402-generic, x86_64)
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 charon: 00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts'
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 charon: 00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/aacerts'
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 charon: 00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 charon: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/acerts'
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 charon: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/ipsec.d/crls'
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332.secrets'
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 charon: 00[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 charon: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon test-vectors aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md4 md5 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac ccm gcm attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark stroke updown eap-mschapv2 xauth-generic
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 charon: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 charon: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 charon: 05[CFG] received stroke: add connection '41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332'
Nov 28 17:24:03 T460 charon: 05[CFG] added configuration '41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332'
Nov 28 17:24:04 T460 charon: 07[CFG] rereading secrets
Nov 28 17:24:04 T460 charon: 07[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
Nov 28 17:24:04 T460 charon: 07[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332.secrets'
Nov 28 17:24:04 T460 charon: 07[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Nov 28 17:24:04 T460 charon: 10[CFG] received stroke: initiate '41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332'
Nov 28 17:24:04 T460 charon: 11[IKE] initiating Main Mode IKE_SA 41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332[1] to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Nov 28 17:24:04 T460 charon: 11[ENC] generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]
Nov 28 17:24:04 T460 charon: 11[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.43.232[500] to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (240 bytes)
Nov 28 17:24:08 T460 charon: 12[IKE] sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Nov 28 17:24:08 T460 charon: 12[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.43.232[500] to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (240 bytes)
Nov 28 17:24:14 T460 NetworkManager[667]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
Nov 28 17:24:14 T460 charon: 00[DMN] signal of type SIGINT received. Shutting down
Nov 28 17:24:14 T460 charon: 00[IKE] destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification
Nov 28 17:24:14 T460 NetworkManager[667]: initiating Main Mode IKE_SA 41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332[1] to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Nov 28 17:24:14 T460 NetworkManager[667]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]
Nov 28 17:24:14 T460 NetworkManager[667]: sending packet: from 192.168.43.232[500] to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (240 bytes)
Nov 28 17:24:14 T460 NetworkManager[667]: sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Nov 28 17:24:14 T460 NetworkManager[667]: sending packet: from 192.168.43.232[500] to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (240 bytes)
Nov 28 17:24:14 T460 NetworkManager[667]: destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification
Nov 28 17:24:14 T460 NetworkManager[667]: establishing connection '41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332' failed
Nov 28 17:24:14 T460 nm-l2tp-service[3759]: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
Nov 28 17:24:14 T460 NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1511889854.5718] vpn-connection[0x55fe5d8fe4e0,41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332,"WorkVPN",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Nov 28 17:24:14 T460 NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1511889854.5779] vpn-connection[0x55fe5d8fe4e0,41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332,"WorkVPN",0]: VPN service disappeared
Nov 28 17:24:14 T460 NetworkManager[667]: <warn>  [1511889854.5803] vpn-connection[0x55fe5d8fe4e0,41d2e76d-a4c4-4f56-bd6a-58ad795af332,"WorkVPN",0]: VPN connection: failed to connect: 'Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying'
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the debug info output:

```
van@z97:/opt/testing$ sudo /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-l2tp-service --debug
nm-l2tp[24282] <debug> nm-l2tp-service (version 1.2.8) starting...
nm-l2tp[24282] <debug>  uses default --bus-name "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.l2tp"
nm-l2tp[24282] <info>  ipsec enable flag: yes
** Message: Check port 1701
** Message: Can't bind to port 1701
nm-l2tp[24282] <warn>  L2TP port 1701 is busy, using ephemeral.
connection
        id : "Work" (s)
        uuid : "71468d41-cd5a-4c91-a70a-c6bc7e1db86a" (s)
        interface-name : NULL (sd)
        type : "vpn" (s)
        permissions : ["user:van:"] (s)
        autoconnect : TRUE (sd)
        autoconnect-priority : 0 (sd)
        autoconnect-retries : -1 (sd)
        timestamp : 0 (sd)
        read-only : FALSE (sd)
        zone : NULL (sd)
        master : NULL (sd)
        slave-type : NULL (sd)
        autoconnect-slaves : ((NMSettingConnectionAutoconnectSlaves) NM_SETTING_CONNECTION_AUTOCONNECT_SLAVES_DEFAULT) (sd)
        secondaries : NULL (sd)
        gateway-ping-timeout : 0 (sd)
        metered : ((NMMetered) NM_METERED_UNKNOWN) (sd)
        lldp : -1 (sd)
        stable-id : NULL (sd)


ipv6
        method : "auto" (s)
        dns : [] (s)
        dns-search : [] (s)
        dns-options : NULL (sd)
        dns-priority : 0 (sd)
        addresses : ((GPtrArray*) 0x5645b3895ae0) (s)
        gateway : NULL (sd)
        routes : ((GPtrArray*) 0x5645b3895ae0) (s)
        route-metric : -1 (sd)
        ignore-auto-routes : FALSE (sd)
        ignore-auto-dns : FALSE (sd)
        dhcp-hostname : NULL (sd)
        dhcp-send-hostname : TRUE (sd)
        never-default : FALSE (sd)
        may-fail : TRUE (sd)
        dad-timeout : -1 (sd)
        dhcp-timeout : 0 (sd)
        ip6-privacy : ((NMSettingIP6ConfigPrivacy) NM_SETTING_IP6_CONFIG_PRIVACY_UNKNOWN) (sd)
        addr-gen-mode : 1 (sd)
        token : NULL (sd)


proxy
        method : 0 (sd)
        browser-only : FALSE (sd)
        pac-url : NULL (sd)
        pac-script : NULL (sd)


vpn
        service-type : "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.l2tp" (s)
        user-name : "van" (s)
        persistent : FALSE (sd)
        data : ((GHashTable*) 0x7fef54006de0) (s)
        secrets : ((GHashTable*) 0x7fef54006cc0) (s)
        timeout : 0 (sd)


ipv4
        method : "auto" (s)
        dns : [] (s)
        dns-search : [] (s)
        dns-options : NULL (sd)
        dns-priority : 0 (sd)
        addresses : ((GPtrArray*) 0x5645b38957a0) (s)
        gateway : NULL (sd)
        routes : ((GPtrArray*) 0x5645b3895a00) (s)
        route-metric : -1 (sd)
        ignore-auto-routes : FALSE (sd)
        ignore-auto-dns : FALSE (sd)
        dhcp-hostname : NULL (sd)
        dhcp-send-hostname : TRUE (sd)
        never-default : FALSE (sd)
        may-fail : TRUE (sd)
        dad-timeout : -1 (sd)
        dhcp-timeout : 0 (sd)
        dhcp-client-id : NULL (sd)
        dhcp-fqdn : NULL (sd)


nm-l2tp[24282] <info>  starting ipsec
Stopping strongSwan IPsec failed: starter is not running
Starting strongSwan 5.5.1 IPsec [starter]...
Loading config setup
Loading conn '71468d41-cd5a-4c91-a70a-c6bc7e1db86a'
found netkey IPsec stack
nm-l2tp[24282] <info>  Spawned ipsec up script with PID 24345.
initiating Main Mode IKE_SA 71468d41-cd5a-4c91-a70a-c6bc7e1db86a[1] to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]
sending packet: from 192.168.0.2[500] to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (240 bytes)
sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
sending packet: from 192.168.0.2[500] to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (240 bytes)
nm-l2tp[24282] <warn>  Timeout trying to establish IPsec connection
nm-l2tp[24282] <info>  Terminating ipsec script with PID 24345.
Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification
establishing connection '71468d41-cd5a-4c91-a70a-c6bc7e1db86a' failed
nm-l2tp[24282] <warn>  Could not establish IPsec tunnel.

(nm-l2tp-service:24282): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After spending a few hours digging around, I found out what the problem is, and the solution.

The problem:

1. Linux no longer supports the 3DES cipher, but many appliances still use it.
2. Kubuntu 17.10 is missing phase1 and phase2 algorithm entry fields under **IPSec Settings** (this is a known bug), which are needed to setup an L2TP/IPSec connection to use 3DES.

The solution:

1. Install the latest version of KDE Plasma from the "backports" PPA.
2. Reboot, then create a new L2TP/IPSec VPN connection - phase1 and phase2 algorithm entry fields should now be present.
3. For the Phase1 Algorithm, enter: 3des-sha1-modp1024!
4. For the Phase2 Algorithm, enter: 3des-sha1!

From memory, I did the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo reboot
sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp-gnome
sudo apt install strongswan
sudo apt install libstrongswan-extra-plugins
sudo apt install libcharon-extra-plugins
```

Reboot, then add L2TP/IPSec as normal. You should now see the Phase1 and Phase2 algorithm textboxes as show in the attached image.

[image]

It's important to note that the above steps will not work if you have installed the latest Linux kernel (4.14 or higher, I believe), so it is highly likely that this workaround to get L2TP/IPSec working with the 3DES cipher will not work when the up and coming *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is released.

Comment: I'am use 16.04. I try your recommendations but still missing phase1 and phase2 algorithm entry fields. Can you give me your config from /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ ?

Comment: @YuraShinkarev - In my `[vpn]` section I have: `ipsec-esp=3des-sha1` and `ipsec-ike=3des-sha1-modp1024`

Answer (score 13):

I know that this question was in regards to getting L2TP/IPSec working on Kubuntu 17.10. However, 18.04 is out now, and here's how I get **L2TP/IPSec working on Kubuntu 18.04**:

1. `$ sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp`
2. `$ sudo systemctl stop xl2tpd.service`
3. `$ sudo systemctl disable xl2tpd.service`

Messing around with backports is not longer required as the **Phase1 algorithms** and **Phase2 algorithms** text-inputs are now included in the default Network Manager.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me with Kubuntu 19.04. Just one minor correction - step 2 should read: `$ sudo systemctl stop xl2tpd.service`

Comment: thanks, it helped on Kubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ike-scan` (option `--nat-t` for NAT traversal) to ask the VPN server if you need those options:

```
sudo ike-scan vpn.myserver.org
Starting ike-scan 1.9 with 1 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/ike-scan/)
52.x.x.x    Main Mode Handshake returned HDR=(CKY-R=aa91011bd9b543f7) SA=(Enc=3DES Hash=SHA1 Auth=PSK Group=2:modp1024 LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)

Ending ike-scan 1.9: 1 hosts scanned in 0.064 seconds (15.54 hosts/sec).  1 returned handshake; 0 returned notify
```

The outputs `Enc=3DES` and `Hash=SHA1` and `Group=2:modp1024` gives you a hint if you need to adjust the phase algorithms. Note: My network-manager settings has a button which adds `Legacy Proposals` for both Phase1 and Phase2 Algorithms:

- Phase1 Algorithms: `aes256-sha1-ecp384,aes128-sha1-ecp256,3des-sha1-modp1024!`
- Phase2 Algorithms: `aes256-sha1,aes128-sha1,3des-sha1!`

Pick those values you find in the output of `ike-scan`.

Comment: Thank You! This is what was missing. As soon as I added the Phase 1 & 2 algorithm stings, it **worked**.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel 4.14 bug is related to the following commit :

- https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/net/xfrm?h=v4.14.8&id=c9f3f813d462c72dbe412cee6a5cbacf13c4ad5e

That kernel 4.14 commit breaks IPsec transportation mode when a wildcard address is used on the client side as is the case with network-manager-l2tp. The commit was reverted in kernel-4.15-rc1 :

- https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/net/xfrm?h=v4.15-rc1&id=94802151894d482e82c324edf2c658f8e6b96508

Unfortunately the reversion commit reintroduces a stack out-of-bounds bug. We might need to wait for the kernel 4.14 branch to get a fix after kernel 4.15 is released. More details in this netdev linux kernel mailing list thread :

- https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/838470/